# PixiJS - Set container size in px

Tags: pixi.js

So I've started using Pixi and trying to place 3 separate PIXI.Cotnainer's in one PIXI.Container which is rendered by the renderer.

I want those three Containers to have fixed size in px, but I do not get it how to achieve this. Setting the width or height does not work.

So my question is very simple: How to set a Containers width and height to eg. "300px"?

Comment: Are you saying that setting width or height on the container has no effect? Then you are possibly not updating the scene after making the change. You can even test in pixis own online examples and setting width there

Comment: @Hachi could you paste the example please?
I am updating the scene with rAF

Comment: I'm vie mobile currently so it is challenging, but basically if you go here: https://pixijs.github.io/examples/#/basics/container.js and add container.width = 100 to the end and update, it changes. Though it scales at the same time and I don't remember just now, how to fix the scaling if you want to. You could just quickly find something from here: http://www.html5gamedevs.com/forum/15-pixijs/ not easy with mobile to help more atm. Sorry :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I appreciate it, really :) I'll look into it, even though its not what I'm looking for. I read the pixi bounds explanation and its a bit confusing to work with.

Comment: @Hachi I've figured out a workaround on how to achieve what I want, thanks to you. Ty man :)